# What is the default scope of a method in Java?

Tags: java, scope

If I type:

```
 void doThis(){
     System.out.println("Hello Stackoverflow.");
 }
```

what is the default scope of `doThis()`?

Public? Protected? Private?

Answer (score 287, accepted):

The default scope is package-private. All classes in the same package can access the method/field/class. Package-private is stricter than protected and public scopes, but more permissive than private scope.

More information:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html
http://mindprod.com/jgloss/scope.html

Comment: "Package-default is stricter than..."

Comment: Might also be worth mentioning that "package-private" is a good scope to use when exposing methods for external unit testing.

Comment: If this is the case, then why would it ever be necessary to make something public unless you were creating creating a library or anything from which users would be getting functionality for their code?

Comment: @user3858162 Most non-trivial applications are organized into multiple packages, in which case public scope is needed for calling calling methods from other packages.

Answer (score 20):

Anything defined as package private can be accessed by the class itself, other classes within the same package, but not outside of the package, and not by sub-classes.

See [this page](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) for a handy table of access level modifiers...

Answer (score 9):

Without an access modifier, a class member is accessible throughout the package in which it's declared. You can learn more from the [Java Language Specification, §6.6.](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.6)

Members of an interface are always publicly accessible, whether explicitly declared or not.

Answer (score 6):

The default scope is "default". It's weird--see [these](http://www.d.umn.edu/~gshute/java/c2java.html) [references](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/scope.html) for more info.

Comment: Actually it's not: it's package-private

Comment: I can't delete my answer as it's been accepted. I encourage Joe to go with @Esko's answer!

Comment: the second link is broken (and btw it is easy to miss that those are two links)

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 now allows implementation of methods inside an interface itself with **default** scope (and static only).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not giving any modifier to your method then as default it will be Default modifier which has scope within package.
for more info you can refer http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_default_access_specifier_in_Java