# Why interface variable or field more precise are not default?

Tags: java, interface, field, access-specifier

I mean to say that Why cannot I have it default access specifier and please don't tell me that java developer made it like that I know that [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceDef.html) it give me that information ..My real Question why it cannot be default access specifier? Not having it private make sense as then variable will be useless ..But Why not default access specifier?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis FYI I am talking about access specifier

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714791/what-is-the-default-scope-of-a-method-in-java

Comment: Did you read article thoroughly? In that article it is written that : `An interface can contain constant declarations in addition to method declarations. All constant values defined in an interface are implicitly public, static, and final. Once again, these modifiers can be omitted.`

Comment: @BenjaminDale Thanks i made the changes ...:)

Comment: @VimalBera I have made changes to my question please see new version.

Comment: Is anyone still there to make the change in question..I will be pleased for the same..

Answer (score 2):

The important thing is how public the interface itself is. It doesn't make sense to have the interface methods less public than the interface itself. So making interface methods public means they are visible whenever the interface is.

Access modifiers are there to protect implementation details, but if you wanted to hide some method you wouldn't expose it in the interface.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly all values are `public` so that it can be accessed from anywhere.
Second thing,interface variables are `static` because Java interfaces cannot be instantiated in their own right; the value of the variable must be assigned in a static context in which no instance exists.
 and 3rd the `final` modifier ensures the value assigned to the interface variable is a true constant that cannot be re-assigned by program code.

Hope this will answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep in mind that main task of interface is to provide a contract.

That contract is base for any other future operations. So it must be equal for everything.

What you can do is to declare a public, protected, private or (defalut) interface. But as far it goes for his members (methods, fields) the must be public.

The reason why they must, is that if some member would be available for restricted area it would deny main principle that every one should support contract on equals terms.

Would lead to redefinition of concept of interface as we know.

---

In case you need such thing you should more focus on the architecture of your system.